# How to add padding to the vertical scale (X-axis) in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, padding, chart.js2

According to the "[Tick Configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#ticks-configuration)" of Chart.js **version 2.3** it is only possible to set a padding for the ticks on the *Y-axis* ("*horizontal scale*"):

> padding | Number |10 | Padding between the tick label and the axis. **Note: Only applicable to horizontal scales.**

And this works like a charm:

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            padding: 20,
        }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
             // how to set padding here?
        }
    }]
}
```

But the draft says, that I need some padding on the *X-axis* as well

[image]

How can I achieve this using Chart.js?

Maybe it's possible using a plugin?

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for this? I'm in the same boat :-)

Comment: @JesseSchutt Unfortunately not.

Comment: how did you accomplish the space between tick 1 and 2? @lampshade

Comment: @lampshade `off-topic` comment, but can you share your chart JS conf because I am trying to create the same chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your options parameter:

```
options: {
   scales: {
       x: {
        ticks: {
           padding: 10
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 12):

Late to the game here, but the solution with latest Chart.js is to include this in your `options` parameter:

```
{
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          padding: 20
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass value to 'tickMarkLength' in 
options--> scales--> xAxes--> gridLines

```
xAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
   tickMarkLength: 10
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is the following for version 2.8:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                padding: 100
            }
        }], 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For echarts version 5:

```
grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '10%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
```